# Algorithm to find closest document containing a set of strings, or variations of them

Tags: distance, similarities, word-embeddings, cosine-similarity, embeddings

I have one dataset (A) containing several fields (strings) per sample. One of these fields is a name, and the others are all alphanumeric identifiers.

I have another dataset (B) which contains highly unstructured strings of text which *can* include some of these names or unique identifiers. These strings have a large number of variations in the way they are formatted, so creating rules and/or regular expressions to try to extract the fields is probably not achievable.

Two big issues are that:

- the names in B may be slight variations of the names in A
- the unique identifiers from A may be truncated or concatenated with other characters in B or may have spaces within them

I would like to create an algorithm to find the closest match(es) from B for each of the samples in A, based on how many of the fields in A's samples are contained in each string in B. If a sample in B contains all of the fields of a sample of A, then it should be an extremely close/perfect match.

There is at most a 1-1 match between samples in the two datasets, but there may be many samples that have similar data, hence why I want to find the closest/best match, or even a list of the best matches to choose from.

Unfortunately, my actual data is banking transactions so I cannot share it. I have tried to simulate an explainable example of data below. Each row in dataset B below is an example of a match for the corresponding row in dataset A. I have highlighted the parts which match.

**Dataset A:**

```
name               id1        id2       id3
---------------------------------------------------
John Smith         AJM4268    455997407 AB012423
Jane Doe           8939BQDFWS 455956471 AB019472
Frank Andrew Jones 849281     456090494 XE039130
```

**Dataset B:**

```
SB-TRANSFER SBN124092095 SB REF.-:45599740730086733 MR JOHN P SMITH Value DATE, 01/01/22 - AB012423 B/O SOME ORG LTD
                                  ^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                        ^^^^^^^^
BANKNET BNKE107589639204132 AB0194 FROM - 10582390183 APR 22;8939BQDFWS BNK REF.-455956471
                            ^^^^^^                           ^^^^^^^^^^          ^^^^^^^^^
EST LOCALTRANSFER ESTX3843940734 JONES MR F A TRANSFER; EST REF .-849281;MSG-45609 0494 VALUE DATE 03-03-22 - XE039130
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^                     ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^                       ^^^^^^^^
```

My initial intuition would be that using embeddings somehow would work well. However, I am not aware of a way to do this since the values in dataset A would be substrings of the values in dataset B.

Answer (score 0):

Word embeddings are better for capturing information realated to the concept and meaning of each term considering the context in each sentence that a word/term might be present.
If you just want to compare string and find the most similar one(s), it might more useful to consider a metric like levenshtein distance in order to be able to compare any available pair of strings.